# Rails Nested Fields Nil but still show in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

I am trying to display a nested attribute in the form, even when the nested attribute is nil.   For example

```
<%= f.fields_for :package_survey_image do |image_form|%>
  <% if PackageSurvey::Image.where(id:f.object[:package_survey_image_id]).count != 0 %>
        <%= image_tag PackageSurvey::Image.find(f.object[:package_survey_image_id]).logo.url(:medium) %>
  <% end %>
        <%= image_form.file_field :logo %>
<%end %>
```

So if the package_survey_image is nil or empty I will want the view to display a browse button to upload the image.  I do not want to instantiate package_survey_image in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you don't want to instantiate it in the controller, that is where it should be done. I would do the following in the controller:

```
@obj.image.build if @obj.image.blank?
```

Then in the view:

```
<%= f.fields_for :package_survey_image do |image_form|%>
<%= image_form.file_field :logo %>
<% end %>

<% if @obj.package_survey_image %>
# Display the image. 
<% end %>
```